# Unexpected "\x00" : vite.config.js

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
basic-react-app@0.0.0 dev
vite

X [ERROR] Unexpected "\x00"

    vite.config.js:1:346:
      1 │ ...React/basic-react-app/vite.config.js";...
        ╵                                          ^

failed to load config from C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
vite.config.js:1:346: ERROR: Unexpected "\x00"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1651:15)
    at C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1059:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1486:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1057:7)
    at C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1086:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:704:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:764:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\sachx\webdapnacollege\React\basic-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:680:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)
```

I ve set my basic react app in my vs code and installed vite@latest and node modules but when I run command `npm run dev` it reflect this error